# Report saved file as parameters name

Tags: reporting-services, reporting

I have a report that is going to be saved as .doc or .pdf, my boss wants the name of this file to be saved as the parameters name [it could contain multiple values], but he chooses the file format.

how can I get this done in reporting services?

thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't from Report Manager whihc is where I suspect you mean

You'd have to wrap a call to ReportServer using SOAP, passing in parameters externally, and renaming in your wrapper. The wrapper would be ASP.NET or WinForms or such.

Alternatively, you may be able to have a [custom renderer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154606.aspx)

Edit: what your boss asks isn't always possible, even for your boss...

Comment: It would have to be in reporting services, cause I do not know much about asp.net or winforms :P

Comment: from what I read in that article [custom renderer], I did not see where you can save the file as the parameters name.

Comment: @Carlos: you'd have to write code to make a custom renderer to read parameters. You **can not** do it in SSRS out of the box

Answer (score -1):

override or handle render method and customize the file name based on parameters provided

Comment: How can I do that? I never heard of this.